# cakephp json webservice for beginners

Tags: json, web-services, rest, cakephp

I am beginner in cakephp
my task is to create restfull json web services
I have started from posts table
give my link to basic json webservice 
I have googled but some are for previous versions
some are for xml
I am not getting started
I have cakephp 2.4 version

currently
my controller is

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        //$posts= $this->Post->find('all');
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
        //$this->set($posts);
    }
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        if(!$id)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('View Not Found'));
        }
        $posts = $this->Post->findById($id);
        if(!$posts)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('View Not Found'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('posts', 'posts'));
    }

 }
```

View is

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(compact('posts', 'posts'));
?>
```

1- it is showing within default html template, I need pure json
2- it show each record as in Post array, don't need subarray
that's it show like this

```
{"posts":{"Post":{"id":"1","title":"The title","body":"This is the post body.","created":"2014-02-08 00:35:50","modified":null}}}
```

while I need

```
{"posts":[{"id":"1","title":"The title","body":"This is the post body.","created":"2014-02-08 00:35:50","modified":null}},{"id":"2","title":"A title once again","body":"And the post body follows.","created":"2014-02-08 00:35:50","modified":null}]}
```

Comment: we can't help you unless you provide some code that proves you spent time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [friendsofcake/crud](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud) plugin. It has an [Api Transform listener](http://friendsofcake.com/crud/docs/listeners/api-transformation.html) to generate the json format you need.

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation describes how to create a RESTful site and it has a section about XML and json views as well.

- [CakePHP and REST](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html)
- [XML and json Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)

Try the documentation, there are plenty of code examples as well.